# Push Rack-Jekyll app to Heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku, rubygems, jekyll

I haven't used Ruby. I don't know what gems are. But I know how to install them and do basic things like that.

I heard of Jekyll and decided to start my own using Heroku. I found Rack-Jekyll that will work on Heroku.

I created my site as per Jekyll instructions and it is running fine on my system. Then I did what I was told to do in http://github.com/bry4n/rack-jekyll#readme. But when I push it to Heroku, I get an error:

```
---> Heroku received push
---> Rack app detected
---> Installing rack-jekyll from http://rubygems.org
     ERROR: could not find gem "rack-jekyll" locally or in a repository
```

On seeing this, I downloaded the rack-jekyll.gem file and committed it to the repsitory and tried uploading it. Even that didn't work. Can you tell me precisely what to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated (ht Andrew):** use heroku's [Bundler support](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler)

create a `Gemfile` like so

```
 source "http://rubygems.org"
 gem "rack-jekyll"
```

Comment: This answer is a little old. The `.gems` manifest approach has been deprecated. Just use [Bundler](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler) and create a `Gemfile`